# Finding the total count and number of items after groupby in apache spark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I need to find the average number of `deviceType` entities per `category`.

I have read the data into a csv file and from that csv file I have a created a dataframe which has `category` and `deviceType`.

I read the dataframe:

```
test_df.groupby('category').count().show()
```

It displays "category" column and "count" column

How do I get:

- total number of items grouped "category" column, and
- sum of all items in count column.

I need to:

- read those two, and
- take the total number of items in all rows of count column, and
- divide by number of items in category column

Comment: can you provide a small reproducible data set and desired data set (output)?

Comment: Tried to clarify your question but it is still not clear what you are trying to ask. Your question originally ended with 'and' so it is not even clear that you finished listing the steps you wanted to list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo:

```
>>> df.show()
+--------+---+
|category|val|
+--------+---+
|    cat1| 13|
|    cat2| 12|
|    cat3| 23|
|    cat1| 20|
|    cat1| 10|
|    cat2| 30|
|    cat3| 11|
|    cat1|  7|
+--------+---+

>>> res = df.groupBy('category').count()
>>> res.show()
+--------+-----+
|category|count|
+--------+-----+
|    cat2|    2|
|    cat3|    2|
|    cat1|    4|
+--------+-----+

>>> res.groupBy().agg({"category":"count","count":"sum"}).show()
+----------+---------------+
|sum(count)|count(category)|
+----------+---------------+
|         8|              3|
+----------+---------------+
```

**UPDATE:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

>>> res.groupBy() \
...    .agg({"category":"count","count":"sum"}) \
...    .withColumnRenamed("sum(count)","sum_cats") \
...    .withColumnRenamed("count(category)","uniq_cats") \
...    .select("uniq_cats","sum_cats",expr("sum_cats/uniq_cats as avg_cats")) \
...    .show()
+---------+--------+------------------+
|uniq_cats|sum_cats|          avg_cats|
+---------+--------+------------------+
|        3|       8|2.6666666666666665|
+---------+--------+------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Could you please also help me finding the average , it would be sum/count or 8/3. Thanks

Comment: Could you please let me know if there any median functions to use it on above data?